# How to order GitHub forks by stars, watchers, commits using the GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api, git-fork

For a given repository, we can view its forks by replacing 'username' and 'repo' in the following URL:

```
https://github.com/username/repo/network/members
```

Example: https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/network/members

#### Question

Using the GitHub API, how can we order a repository's forks by

1. stars
2. watchers
3. commits (since forking)

Note: accessible wrappers are fine (e.g. using python library for GitHub API)

#### What I know so far

We could write a script to individually retrieve the metrics for each of the ~500 forks. This may be the best/simplest solution, although I do know GitHub has a lot of built in (hidden) features, so I do wonder if collecting the most active forks may have been considered and built into the API by GitHub. Iterating through hundreds/thousands of forks could also invoke the GitHub API's rate limiting, so please be mindful if using this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer, but it is possible to order by stargazers using GraphQL API (try [GitHub GraphQL API Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) for quick start!):

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "vuejs", name: "vue") {
    forks(orderBy: {field: STARGAZERS, direction: DESC}, first: 3) {
      nodes {
        nameWithOwner
        stargazerCount
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "forks": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "nameWithOwner": "SmallComfort/react-vue",
            "stargazerCount": 1198
          },
          {
            "nameWithOwner": "supergaojian/vue",
            "stargazerCount": 20
          },
          {
            "nameWithOwner": "developedbyed/vue",
            "stargazerCount": 13
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Possible fields are:

```
enum RepositoryOrderField {
  """
  Order repositories by creation time
  """
  CREATED_AT

  """
  Order repositories by name
  """
  NAME

  """
  Order repositories by push time
  """
  PUSHED_AT

  """
  Order repositories by number of stargazers
  """
  STARGAZERS

  """
  Order repositories by update time
  """
  UPDATED_AT
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a project for that: [Useful Forks](https://useful-forks.github.io/).
I have tried it and it works perfect as long as the fork didn't change its original name.