# How to use github API v4 or v3 to get the "highest starred fork repo" of a selected repo?

Tags: github, github-api

How to use GitHub API v4 or v3 to get the "highest starred fork repo" of a selected repo?

By this
I think we need to get all the forks first (maybe huge)
and then filter out the most starred one.

Is this thought correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66611801/8810271

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order GitHub forks by stars, watchers, commits using the GitHub API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66609900/how-to-order-github-forks-by-stars-watchers-commits-using-the-github-api)